# What does “bullying beat” mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

There was the following line in New Yorker’s (January 18) weekend book review titled, “A Startup Fairy Tale and the Dark Side of Yoga.”

> “Emily Bazelon **returns to the bullying beat** in this week’s New York
>   Times Magazine, in a story about bullies, their victims, and a third
>   party of Internet activists that seeks justice when authorities
>   won’t.”

http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/books/2014/01/weekend-reading-a-startup-fairy-tale.html

I don’t think I’ve met the word, "bullying beat" before. What doe’s “*Emily Bazelon returns to the bullying beat*” mean?

Is “the bullying beat” a common English word ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Beat* is used here in the sense of “the territory someone regularly observes”. It was first used of watchmen and policemen, but has for a century also been applied to journalists: reporters “cover” the *sports beat*, the *city hall beat*, the *theatre beat*.

So saying Ms. Bazelon “returns to the bullying beat” means that bullying is a subject she is familiar with and has often written about in the past.

Comment: As a sidenote, to expand a bit, the phrase "walk the beat" means to "patrol", usually in the context of a police officer or watchman patrolling along an assigned route.